# Chrome debugger hanging

Tags: google-chrome, javascript-debugger

Recently when I open up the chrome debugger it hangs. 
I load up my page in the browser and it works fine. When I open the debugger the elements tab shows only 4 lines of html. Should have hundreds. Opening any script shows a blank page. After opening the page becomes totally unresponsive. To close the browser page I have to click multiple times on X to kill the tab.

The only way I can get it to work is to open the debugger before I load the page and then load the page.. However as I have a lot of breakpoints this is tedious..

Has anyone else had this issue..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I just faced similar problem today but then realized that it was because I was using web workers. I had some breakpoints in my worker so the whole screen was paused but not highlighted. There was no indication from dev tool that it is paused at breakpoint. Although it was showing paused in main thread.